# How to get a blob from selected files on GooglePicker

Tags: google-api, google-api-js-client, google-picker

I am using GooglePicker with React, and the result I am getting is an array of objects...

```
[
  {
    "id": "1...m",
    "serviceId": "docs",
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "name": "name.jpg",
    "description": "",
    "type": "photo",
    "lastEditedUtc": 1575388407136,
    "iconUrl": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/jpeg",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1...m/view?usp=drive_web",
    "embedUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1...m/preview?usp=drive_web",
    "sizeBytes": 111364,
    "rotation": 0,
    "rotationDegree": 0,
    "parentId": "0...A"
}]
```

So I tried to access through `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files` and directly through `file.url` using

`` const fetchOptions = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }; ``

```
docs.forEach((file) => {
  ...
  fetch(file.url, fetchOptions).then((res) => {
    const blob = res.blob();
    uploadFile(blob);
  });
});
```

But I get `403` or `CORS`; I tried setting the `relayUrl` in the picker, but this broke the Picker.

Notes:

1. I have these 3 scopes in my auth2:

   ````
       ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']```
   ````
2. I have my computer's url with port and protocol set as Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs

Any ideas?

---

Edit 1:

I also tried using Google API like this:

```
const FILE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files';
const url = isDoc
        ? `${FILE_URL}/${file.id}/export?mimeType=${mimeType}`
        : `${FILE_URL}/${file.id}?alt=media`;

      fetch(url, fetchOptions).then((res) => {
        const blob = res.blob();
        uploadFile(blob);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You'll need the Drive API

From your question it seems that you are trying to do everything with Google Picker. However, the picker will only get you limited metadata for the files, so you can open them with your account (i.e. see them in another window) or let you upload files. If you want to *download* the actual file, then you will need to use the Drive API.

[Drive Quickstart for browser JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)

The flow might be:

- let user pick file
- get metadata object
- extract file id from object
- make a call to Drive API ([`get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) with `alt='media'`)

If I have misunderstood and you are already using the Drive API, then it would be helpful to see the associated code with that.

#### Ref

- [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)
- [`get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [`export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export))

## EDIT:

Here is an example of using the Picker API to feed into the Drive API with `gapi` using the same login client.

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
    onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
    onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```js
const API_KEY = 'AI...';
const CLIENT_ID = '44...';
const appId = "44...";

const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"];

const DISCOVERY_DOCS = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest",
];

const authorizeButton = document.getElementById("authorize_button");
const signoutButton = document.getElementById("signout_button");

// Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load("client:auth2:picker", initClient);
}

function initClient() {
  gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES[0]
    })
    .then(
      function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(handleSignIn);

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        handleSignIn(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
      },
      function (error) {
        appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      }
    );
}

function handleSignIn(isSignedIn) {
  if (isSignedIn) {
    authorizeButton.style.display = "none";
    signoutButton.style.display = "block";
    createPicker();
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.display = "block";
    signoutButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

function handleSignoutClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

function createPicker() {
  const token = gapi.client.getToken().access_token
  if (token) {
    
    let view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
    view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
    let picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
      .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
      .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
      .setAppId(appId)
      .setOAuthToken(token)
      .addView(view)
      .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
      .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
      .setCallback(getFile)
      .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  }
}

function getFile(pickerResp) {
  gapi.client.drive.files
    .get({
      fileId: pickerResp.docs[0].id,
      alt: 'media'
    })
    .then(resp => {
      console.log("fetch response", resp.status)
      let binary = resp.body
      // EDIT - addition from Gabrielle vvvv
      let l = binary.length
      let array = new Uint8Array(l);
      for (var i = 0; i<l; i++){
        array[i] = binary,charCodeAt(i);
      }
      let blob = new Blob([array], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
      // EDIT - addition from Gabrielle ^^^^
}
```

This code is adapted from the [Drive Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) and the [Picker Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs).

**Note** - this does give an error in the console, but it does seem to work all the same. This does seem to be a bug with the Picker - https://issuetracker.google.com/177046274

**EDIT from Gabrielle**
**Note** - using get with `alt = media` is for binary files. To get sheets/docs/slides etc, you need to use the `export` end point.

Comment: Hi :)

Yeah, I also tried to use google api like this: ```const url = isDoc ?`${FILE_URL}/${file.id}/export?mimeType=${mimeType}` : `${FILE_URL}/${file.id}?alt=media`; fetch(url, fetchOptions).then((res) => {.....``` where `FILE_URL` is `const FILE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files';` but this gives me CORS

Comment: Can you explain what kind of process you are trying to do? User selects file for what purpose?

Comment: I have a common upload storage, so user selects the file so I can get a copy of that and upload to my own storage and display inside my app. So I either need the blob or a public url...

Comment: @Gabrielle - I have updated my answer with an example in plain JS. Does this work for you?

Comment: I am getting this: `conv20 provider error: File doesn't seem to be a valid image (idx 0)` when trying to access the blob

Comment: Is the file you selected a valid image?

Comment: Yes, it is a "jpg" from my drive that works everywhere...

Comment: That is strange...I tested this on my end and it works with a jpg file also. hmm. What line does it fail on? Is it a very large image?

Comment: Are you using the example exactly as I have above?

Comment: It works, but body is not a blob.... it is a binary. but thank you very much :))) I did this: 
`let binary = resp.body
          let l = binary.length
          var array = new Uint8Array(l);
          for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){
              array[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          var blob = new Blob([array], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});` to make it work

Comment: if is it not too much work, can you add this observation on your answer so whoever gets in here know the full scenario? Thank you SO much

Comment: Also, this only work for non-gdrive files... I think for gDrive we need to use export not get...

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you for the correction, I have updated the answer.