# google-picker image search 403，We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page

Tags: google-image-search, google-picker

google drive ImageSearchView is deprecated，how can i use the image search now？

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
        addView(google.picker.ViewId.IMAGE_SEARCH).
        setLocale('fr').
        setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
        setCallback(pickerCallback).
        build();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Set the Mime Type

```js
let view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
let picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
    .setAppId(appId)
    .setOAuthToken(token)
    .addView(view)
    .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
    .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
    .setCallback(handlePick)
    .build();
picker.setVisible(true);
```

For a full set up I would recommend looking at getting the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) working.

You can also see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962609/how-to-get-a-blob-from-selected-files-on-googlepicker/66964765#66964765) of mine in which an example of using the picker to then call the Drive API to get the blob of an image.

#### Reference

- [Picker Docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs)